# Trouble getting an element using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click on a button on a webpage but I'm not succeeding in finding that element. I've tried all sorts of XPATH and ID options, but they don't seem to work.

```
testButton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@id="maintoolbarviewbutton-btnIconEl"]')
testButton.click()
```

I've also tried it with class, type. Tried it with //input, //a, //span. The HTML is as follows:
https://gist.github.com/VoidCallerZ/57404adbf8b16f9594596d7a5c1216d8

It's in N-Able Monitoring. I'm trying to click on "View" and then "Wallboard"

Comment: Please check if it inside any Iframe. In that case, you have to switch to that frame and then try to click on the desired element.

Answer (score 0):

If you can give the url and the complete code, I would be able to figure it out. In dev mode, if you select the XPath and copy the XPath, you should be able to get the Xpath. Please see the following step by step and ensure whether all the steps are added.

```
from selenium import webdriver as wd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

dr = wd.chrome()
url = '<url>'
dr.get(url)
testButton = dr.find_element(By.XPATH,'//button[@id="maintoolbarviewbutton-btnIconEl"]')
testButton.click()
```